# Adjust element styles dynamically in Axure

Tags: axure

Is it possible to adjust element styles dynamically in Axure using triggers?

For example, I want to display table cell in bold when user clicks a button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to achieve the element styles dynamically on click of a Button.

Step 1: Select all the Table cells you want to Bold and then Go to Interaction Styles. Go under Selected option and tick out the BOLD (Click to toggle BOLD) .

Step 2: Create a Button and add case 'Onclick' action. This will open up a new window where you can select 'Set Selected/Checked' option and select all the table cells you wish to have the dynamic effect on.

Step 3: After selecting all the elements/Table cells , you have to set selected state to 'Value' and 'Toggle' options from respective drop down menus.

Click on the button 'Click Here' to see the Bold Effect on Table Cell(s).

See the demo link of Axure RP8:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aRWZ8s_J1A1iyszez4qR8i9aelVeObK5

Happy Wireframing :)

Comment: Probably after 3 years but it's really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make element selected or disabled through trigger and customize corresponding style of this element.

Answer (score 0):

Table cells also have events and selected states.
You can add a case to toggle the selected state.
Use the interaction states to adjust the formatting of the cell.

See the demo file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzsls7chii1xy6c/Table.rp?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and quite simple once you know how. This answer is for Axure RP 8.

Unfortunately, I don't know of a property that changes the text to bold, but what you can do is create two different text objects (widgets). One with regular text, one with bold text.

Set the bold one to Hidden:

- Select the bold text object.
- In the **Inspector** pane, choose the **Style** tab.
- Top right of this tab is a checkbox that says **Hidden**. Check it.

Configure the button to show the bold text:

- Select the button in question.
- Head back to the **Inspector** pane and select the **Properties** tab.
- Double click **OnClick**.
- From the left column (actions) of the dialogue box that appears, choose **Show/Hide**.
- In the right column (Configure actions), choose the regular widget.
- Set the visibility to **Hide**.
- In the right column (Configure actions), choose the bold widget.
- Set the visibility to **Show**.